# How to call a function in a C++ Windows Desktop Application without interaction with interface

Tags: c++, sockets, desktop

I'm trying to do a server/client desktop application in C++. 
I have created the server/client classes first in a console application and they work. They can send and receive informatión between them.

Now I'm trying to create a desktop application and create a UI.

I created a Windows Desktop Application in VisualStudio(2015). I think this kind of applications work with events. **I need to run my client "ReceiveFromServerAndPrint()" function but I don't know where should I place it.** I tried it in the main message loop but it is not working

**So, I would like to know how can I call a function of my class "Client" repeatedly without interaction with the user interface required.**

Hope you can help me. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the question? Please [edit] your post and provide a [mcve].

Comment: I edited it. Do you think is more clear now? Sorry, I have to learn how to ask here too.

Comment: @CarlosHernández you posted a sample from MSDN with a lot of GUI code.Your question is not about GUI. It is very complex - about network communication, asynchronous programming and other. You need to create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrate your problem with a couple lines of code, because currently you are a candidate for [downvoting](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/).

Comment: You need to start with writing 2 applications that do nothing except sending and receiving data with sockets. Start learning with [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winsock/finished-server-and-client-code) and create your own.

Comment: "call a function of my class "Client" repeatedly" - you mean you want to call it every minute, say? MSDN's [Using Timers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/using-timers) to get periodic messages to WndProc, and then in the code that handles WM_TIMER you'd then kick off a background thread to run your task. Beward that the background thread needs to message back to the window thread to do any UI updates - it can't itself.

Comment: _"I'm trying to give to the client an user interface"_ Use your VS to create an MFC application. You probably need a Dialog kind application.

Comment: Okay, I get it. But the point is (and I don't want to be rude at all. Just to learn) How can I ask someting about how to use a certain standard application of C++/Visual Studio without pasting the code of the application?

Comment: @CarlosHernández you need to post a code that demonstrate your problem. There was no demonstration of network communication, there was no server code, etc. In other words - it was not an example.

Comment: @ZDF don't use MFC. It was deprecated a lot of years ago and not supported.

Comment: Ye, but the problem is not with the server/client communication. That's workin. I just need to embed it in a desktop application :/

I think @Rup understood what I asked but I would like to do it continuously (not with a time step of one second but in kind of a while loop) is it possible?

Comment: @DmitrySazonov MFC 14.15.26706.0 - August 14, 2018

Comment: @ZDF you can also suggest WTL, or other stuff with a lot of legacy and crutches. And it's not supported for UWP target. There are enough modern C++ UI frameworks that are much more powerful and easy to use.